# React Number Easing

Tags: reactjs

Just imported and already a mistake, is it my project or the library?

npm install react-number-easing --save

TypeError: Cannot read property 'any' of undefined

```
 var NumberEasing = React.createClass({
    34 |   displayName: 'NumberEasing',
    35 |   propTypes: {
  > 36 |     value: React.PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    37 |     speed: React.PropTypes.number,
    38 |     ease: React.PropTypes.oneOf(Object.keys(eases)),
    39 |     useLocaleString: React.PropTypes.bool,
```

When I use my code

```
           <NumberEasing
                value={15}
                speed={300}
                ease='quintInOut' />
```

Comment: This is an unsolvable problem for us given the provided information.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `react-number-easing` is based on a version of React which included Proptypes (the module's last release was 4 years ago). The PropTypes property was removed from the React object in v16, so you can either downgrade to React v15 or update the module to use the `prop-types` package by either forking it or submitting a PR.

or **just maybe**..

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

React.PropTypes = PropTypes;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you dont have prop-types installed/imported. Make sure to install and import it in the file as follows:

```
npm install --save prop-types

import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6
var PropTypes = require('prop-types'); // ES5 with npm
```

Read this for detailed explanation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types